# Storing db2 database on secondary hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, db2

I have two hard drives one with os(ubuntu) and other just etc4 formatted. I want to store my database on this second hard drive. I tried searching online but there are very few resources online. It will be really helpful if someone can tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you failed to find any help online because you really don't know what you're doing so here's some clues

- Mount the second hard drive into your filesystem at a convenient location

  - The [FSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) is a good reference for where to locate your files.
  - The [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) command will be needed
  - You'll need to update [fstab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) too.

I don't know much (anything) about db2 but I found [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014028783) document that'll probably be useful to youm, note how the author supplies a location for their database when creating it

> db2 CREATE DATABASE mydb AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES ON '/home/db2inst1' DBPATH ON '/home/db2inst1' USING CODESET ISO-8859-2 TERRITORY SI COLLATE USING SYSTEM PAGESIZE 4096

I hope this puts you on the right path.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, Now I have some direction.